# What is the use of the low pressure helium lamp in this plasma jet experiment?

Tags: optics, laser, spectroscopy, plasma-physics

I would like to ask about this experimental set up. What is the use and significance of the reference cell (Low pressure helium lamp)? Why is it necessary on this set up?

Link to paper is as follows.

https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-6595/ac4e21

[image]

Comment: I think you accidentally linked the wrong paper. Also, you might be able to copy the image file for the figure and upload that instead of a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks let me check again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is part of a laser stabilization or wavelength detection setup.

As long as the laser is on one of the Helium 2P-2S transitions, the beam gets absorbed in the helium lamp and the power on Photo Diode#2 is at a minimum. (Wavelengths: 1082.91, 1083.03 and 1083.03 nm)

With this, you can detect if your laser is at resonance. With a little bit of feedback-loop electronics you can even enable a frequency-lock of the laser.

The paper explicitly mentions this on page 3

> The second beam goes
> through a low-pressure helium discharge to provide the precise
> wavelength positions of the He(2^3PJ –2^3S1) transitions.

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there a relation between pressure broadening and this set up and the reason for using a reference cell based on pressure/collisional broadening?

Comment: Partly yes. Collisional Broadening/Shift as well as Doppler Broadening may still play a significant role in the linewidth.  And while the collisional broadening can be reduced by reducing th pressure you'd still have the Doppler Broadening (few GHz) and another problem left: He(2^3LJ) states are metastable. Thus you want to reduce background gas collisions to enhance their lifetime. But you also have to support a discharge in the lamp to create the metastable states. So there is a tradeoff to make: low pressure: low broadening but hard to maintain the lamp discharge.

Comment: @Julien Kluge Great answers thanks! I'm fascinated by the ongoing role of the reference cell throughout such an experiment. Assuming operation without feedback, since the general spectrum from the reference cell should be quite predictable(?), what reasons are there for an in-experiment reference rather than eg. standard calibrated data? Aside from tracking with lab environment fluctuations, presumably it's important to evaluate the the reference & sample under the same laser state? So is the laser fluctuation of concern? eg. minute changes in laser wavelength, power, polarization?

Comment: Yes, the reference should be quiet precise for the intends and purposes (Shifts << Broadening). The reference cell is just the simplest solution. You need something to compare the light to. You could use a wavemeter or another reference laser or something else but these would not be absolute referenced or/and just more complicated than a helium discharge lamp in the laser beam. - Wavelength: you'd notice that in the measurement; power: yes but can be correlated with PD#1 and corrected for; polarization would convert into power fluctuations. - If you want, you can accept the answer above.

Comment: Sorry @JulienKluge I'm not the OP, just an interested party. Great explanations though ty.

Comment: @IreneodelaCruzJr. are you happy with JulienKluge's answer, if so you can mark it as accepted answer.